# Using more than one value in query to send email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code to send an email after button click.

I want to use aspnet_Users.UserName retrived from the query as part of the email, but it doesnt work.

Below is my code.

Thank you

```
SqlDataReader reader;
string sendMessage = "SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email, aspnet_Users.UserName, User_Profile.FirstName FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN User_Profile ON aspnet_Users.UserId = User_Profile.UserId WHERE (aspnet_Membership.UserId = @UserId)";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sendMessage, myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
    ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
     {
         emailArray.Add(reader["email"]);
         string name = reader["UserName"].ToString();
     }

     foreach (string email in emailArray)
     {

         //send new confirmation email
         const string username = "------------";
         const string password = "------------";
         SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
         MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("-------------", "--------");
         smtpclient.Host = "---------";
         smtpclient.Port = 25;
         mail.From = fromaddress;
         mail.To.Add(email);
         mail.Subject = ("Welcome to -------);
         //mail.Attachments.Add(new mail);
         mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
         mail.Body =
         //the message that goes in the body of the email 
         "+ HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name) + ";

         smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
         smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
         smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
         smtpclient.Send(mail);
     }
     reader.Close();
     myConnection.Close();

 }
```

Comment: You never do anything with `username` in your `while` block.

Comment: @mason thaks, what do u suggest i do with the username in while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
...
while (reader.Read())
{
  emails[Convert.ToString(reader["email"])] = Convert.ToString(reader["UserName"]);
}

foreach(string email in emails.Keys)
{
  ...
  mail.To.Add(email);
  ...
  mail.Body = "Greetings " + emails[email] + "!".
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed 'UserName' from the database into a variable called "name", but later in the code, you try to reference "username" -- which is probably empty.

Comment: Thanks, i have changed the name to reflect properly, but is still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class EmailModel
 {
     public string ToAddress {get; set;}
     public string Username {get; set;}
 }

var myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email, aspnet_Users.UserName, User_Profile.FirstName FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN User_Profile ON aspnet_Users.UserId = User_Profile.UserId WHERE (aspnet_Membership.UserId = @UserId)");
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
var emails = new List<EmailModel>();
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myCommand.Conection = myConnection;
    myConnection.Open();           
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();    
    while (reader.Read())
     {
         emails.Add(new EmailModel(){
             ToAddress = reader["email"].ToString(),
             Username = reader["UserName"].ToString()
         });         
     }
}

foreach (var email in emails)
 {

     //send new confirmation email
     SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
     MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("-------------", "--------");
     smtpclient.Host = "---------";
     smtpclient.Port = 25;
     mail.From = fromaddress;
     mail.To.Add(email.ToAddress);
     mail.Subject = ("Welcome to -------"");
     mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
     mail.Body = "Hi "+email.Username;
     smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
     smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     string smtp_username="";
     string smtp_password="";//better not put this in code, pull it from .config file
     smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtp_username, smtp_password);
     smtpclient.Send(mail);
 }
```

We need to define a class that's going to have the information to use in the email that we've retrieved from the database. Above, you can see I created a new EmailModel class (you should probably put that in a separate file and add more properties as necessary), and I populate it from the database. My code doesn't keep the database connection alive any longer than necessary (why keep it open while actually sending the emails?! That's a waste of resources). I also make use of the generic `List<T>` class instead of the rarely used `ArrayList`.

Then I loop through the EmailModel's in the list and generate an email for each one, using properties from the EmailModel.

Comment: thank you very much for your feeback. i am getting alot of Error 29 The type or namespace name 'Dictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Musa I didn't utilize a dictionary in my code, that was Igor's answer. But the dictionary is in the same namespace as the List<T> class that I did use. Right click the dictionary or list and have Visual Studio add the reference for you by clicking Resolve and then select the `using System.Collections.Generic;` option (that's how you should resolve that type of missing namespace error in the future) . Or manually add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top of your class.